# Plugins to create super customizable landing page with WordPress and Mailchimp

Tags: web-development, wordpress

I would like to use WordPress and Mailchimp to create a super customizable landing page. So I'm looking for plugins to either that would allow me to customize them.

I want to be able to:

- Customize each element of the landing page (font, color, how form elements are displayed, background image etc.)
- Have a double opt-in inside my landing page (not be redirected in the default double opt-in landing page of Mailchimp).
- Save the email in a list on Mailchimp
- Create a WordPress account on my website with the user email address and a default random password
- Send a custom email once the user has been added in the Mailchimp list and created on my website.

WordPress and Mailchimp don't allow that out of the box, so I'm looking for plugins that help me achieve this.

Does anybody had an idea of plugins which I could use and how can I create such a landing page?

Comment: I just edited your question to match the topic of Software Recommendations. I hope I got it right :)

Comment: just curious, why don't you want to use Landing page templates/themes?